# What is the term for a word made from a sentence?

Tags: terminology, word-formation

I thought the term was 'periphrase', but looking that up it that apparently isn't the case. I don't know how I got my terms mixed up.

By 'words made from a sentence', I mean such words as 'forget-me-not' (name of a flower), and 'hand-me-downs'.

I recall that highly synthetic languages like to do this a lot. But when I tried to look up more information about this, I can't find it because it would seem that I have forgotten the proper terminology.

Comment: Synthetic languages have compounds but the examples like *forget-me-not* is a bit different.  In synthetic languages most of the compounds still make syntactic sense and will have some derivational morpheme to make them eg a noun and thus are, if eg a noun, declined normally.  In German the equivalent of *forget-me-not* is declined but some other Satzwörter are not.  In Romance not.  In Slavic languages this type of construction is avoided but if we contrive some then it will not be declined either.

Comment: By the way, some more examples: *tiramisú*, *vasistas*.

Answer (score 1):

I am only aware of the German term *Satzwort* (literally "sentence word") but I don't have an English translation of it. Examples for a *Satzwort* in German are [Kiekindiewelt](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kiekindiewelt) and [Störenfried](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stoerenfried).

Comment: *Satzwort* is perfect.  But I see *Störenfried* more like *robamaridos* and generally https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Verb-noun_compounds_by_language, not a sentence.

Comment: German has verb-noun-compounds, e.g., *Schreibblockade* "writing block", but they are formed from the stem of the verb. The *en* in *Stör-en-fried* (<*stör den Frieden*) is a hint that *Störenfired* is a *satzword* and not a verb-noun-compund.

Comment: It's a different structure.  Endocentric vs exocentric.  *Schreibblockade* is a type of *Blockade*.  But a *Vergissmeinnicht* is not a type of the theoretical noun *nicht*.

Comment: Well, I agree with Duden here who classify these two examples as *Satzwort*.